# Is it possible to trick Perl to use a variable %INC and still keep the global %INC untouched?

Tags: perl, global-variables, require, perlvar

I have just found a script we are using which has a sub that says `my %INC` in it, where it stores some values about incentives, thus `%INC`. This never seemed to be a problem, or no-one ever noticed. For me it produced 20 screens of redefine warnings, because `%INC`, holding all the file names Perl has `do`ne, `require`d or `use`d, was pretty large, and now is `('stuff' => 123)`.

Do I really have to go and rename every single reference to this in the sub, or is there another way to make Perl forgive this ... ?

---

Here's a part of the output of:

```
print Dumper \%INC; # I added this line
my %INC;             
print Dumper \%INC; # I added this line
exit;               # I added this line
```

Output:

```
          [...]
          'SqlConnect.pm' => 'lib1/SqlConnect.pm',
          'Lib/RateRequest.pm' => 'Lib/RateRequest.pm'
        };
$VAR1 = {};
[Fri Jun 29 16:09:13 2012] live_batch_test.pl: Subroutine export_fail redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Carp.pm line 43.
[Fri Jun 29 16:09:13 2012] live_batch_test.pl: Subroutine _cgc redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Carp.pm line 45.
[Fri Jun 29 16:09:13 2012] live_batch_test.pl: Subroutine longmess redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Carp.pm line 51.
[Fri Jun 29 16:09:13 2012] live_batch_test.pl: Subroutine shortmess redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/Carp.pm line 71.
[...] (Snipped like 20 screens of redefine warnings)
```

The warnings only show if I create an object of one of my classes (which happens to contain `SOAP::WSDL` so it has a lot of stuff in it). I'm not sure why those are redefine warnings. If `%INC` is empty, how can it know stuff is being redefined?

---

**Update:**

It seems you actually **can** create a lexical `my %INC`.

```
use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%INC;
{
  my %INC = ('asdf' => 'asdf');
  print Dumper \%INC;
}
print Dumper \%INC;
```

Produces (snipped):

```
          'feature.pm' => 'C:/Perl/lib/feature.pm'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'asdf' => 'asdf'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'warnings/register.pm' => 'C:/Perl/lib/warnings/register.pm',
```

The problem in my case does not seem to be the `my %INC`, but rather the `%INC = &sub_that_has_my_percent_INC_and_returns_it()` in the script that I actually have to `require`. Now that, in turn, also has `use vars qw(%INC)`. Replacing it... well, I'm not sure what that is going to break.

Comment: I'm going to have a fun chat with the guy who built this...

Comment: local %INC; would have made more sense. I guess you can't change it now without causing unintended consequences, right?

Comment: @mkb: no, I mean `%INC`.

Comment: And it is not used to tell Perl something in the way `%INC` is meant to be used. There is just a variable that has the same name because the guy who built it didn't know about `%INC` being a reserved name. It just has some data in it that the sub needs.

Comment: Cause global search and replace on a file is so difficult?

Comment: Yes, you can create it. So what? It have exactly zero special meaning.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I posted what I did to get rid of it. I'm going to accept @eugeney's answer since he answered the question in the topic most accurately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global variable `%INC` (or `%main::INC` or `%::INC`) is a completely different variable from the lexically scoped `%INC`, created with `my`. You can safely use `my %INC` in your subroutine.

Comment: I don't think so. I edited the question to show what the warnings look like.

Comment: Checked that myself just now, see edited question. Problem lies one layer higher. Still very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Defining lexicaly scoped `my %INC` is possible, but this variable have absolutely no special meaning. Perl only considers global `%INC` when working with module system.

Your problem is elsewhere

Just to entertain you with examples, given:

Aaa.pm

```
package Aaa;
warn "Aaa loaded!";

1;
```

inc.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Aaa;
require Aaa;
warn 1, Dumper \%INC;
{
    my %INC;
    use Aaa;
    require Aaa;
    warn 2, Dumper \%INC;
}
warn 3, Dumper \%INC;
my %INC;
use Aaa;
require Aaa;

sub again {
    my %INC;
    require Aaa;
    warn 4, Dumper \%INC;
}

again();
warn 5, Dumper \%INC;
```

You will only see global `%INC` in 1 and 3, without whatever changes to lexical ones and `Aaa.pm` will still be loaded exactly once.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I just figured that out also. The problem is that in the next script there is a `use vars '%INC'` and several `sub`s that share the `%INC` returned by the sub that has `my %INC`. I'm trying to get rid of that now.

Answer (score 1):

`perldoc vars` says that the `vars` pragma has been superseded by the `our` keyword.

Following the documentation's advice seems to work for me:

```
package Incentives;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'dump';

our %INC = ( abc => 123 );

dump \%INC;                   # ( abc => 123 ),
                              # different under use vars '%INC';

use List::Util;               # Loads just fine

package Test;

use Data::Dump 'dump';

dump \%Incentives::INC;       # ( abc => 123 )
dump \%main::INC;             # reference to global %INC

1;
```

Comment: That is correct. But in my case the `use vars`/`our %INC` was not in a `package`, but in `main::`. I've adjusted your code and now it shows the warnings. Before the `our %INC` it has the normal values. After it, it there is the `abc => 123` as well as a couple of proper values like `Exporter.pm`, `List/Util.pm` and `vars.pm`. I think with `our` it just deleted the ones defined in `main::` and left the ones that came from `Test`. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have problems if you touch the global package variable `%INC`, but you can create all the lexicals named `%INC` you want and it won't be a problem.

```
$ perl -e'require CGI; my %INC; require CGI;'

$ perl -e'require CGI; local %INC; require CGI;'
Subroutine export_fail redefined at .../Carp.pm line 64.
Subroutine _cgc redefined at .../Carp.pm line 66.
Subroutine longmess redefined at .../Carp.pm line 72.
Subroutine shortmess redefined at .../Carp.pm line 92.
Subroutine croak redefined at .../Carp.pm line 100.
Subroutine confess redefined at .../Carp.pm line 101.
Subroutine carp redefined at .../Carp.pm line 102.
Subroutine cluck redefined at .../Carp.pm line 103.
Constant subroutine Carp::CALLER_OVERRIDE_CHECK_OK redefined at .../Carp.pm line 108.
Subroutine caller_info redefined at .../Carp.pm line 114.
Subroutine format_arg redefined at .../Carp.pm line 181.
Subroutine get_status redefined at .../Carp.pm line 213.
Subroutine get_subname redefined at .../Carp.pm line 222.
Subroutine long_error_loc redefined at .../Carp.pm line 240.
Subroutine longmess_heavy redefined at .../Carp.pm line 268.
Subroutine ret_backtrace redefined at .../Carp.pm line 276.
Subroutine ret_summary redefined at .../Carp.pm line 309.
Subroutine short_error_loc redefined at .../Carp.pm line 324.
Subroutine shortmess_heavy redefined at .../Carp.pm line 348.
Subroutine str_len_trim redefined at .../Carp.pm line 361.
Subroutine trusts redefined at .../Carp.pm line 376.
Subroutine trusts_directly redefined at .../Carp.pm line 396.
Constant subroutine CGI::XHTML_DTD redefined at .../constant.pm line 151.
Subroutine _ops_to_nums redefined at .../overloading.pm line 10.
Subroutine import redefined at .../overloading.pm line 19.
Subroutine unimport redefined at .../overloading.pm line 37.
```

What you said doesn't jive. You must be changing the global `%INC` instead of a lexical one somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the simple example. You're right of course. I was (made to do it). In [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11265936/1331451) I explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

try with

`no warnings 'redefine';`

in that subroutine, although, this might have some interesting side effects in the future

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to not show the warnings, I'm trying to solve a big faux pas.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the actual problem and a way to deal with it.

There are two files that I did not create.

`file1.pl` has some subs. One of these subs does something like this:

```
sub foo {
  my %INC = (foo => 'bar'); # lexical variable, does not mess with global %INC
  return %INC;
}
```

`file2.pl` looks like this:

```
use vars qw(%INC);     # oops! global variable
require 'file1.pl';

sub bar1 {
  if (!$INC{'foo'}) {
    %INC = &foo();     # this is breaking stuff
  }
  my $hashref = {
    'inc' => \%INC,
  }
  return $hashref;
}

sub bar2 {
  if (!$INC{'foo2'}) {
    %INC = &foo();
  }
}
# and so on
```

In `file3.pl` which I created, I have:

```
use MyModule;
require 'file2.pl';

my $data = &bar1();
my $obj = MyModule->new();
$obj->doStuff();
```

Now when I call the `doStuff()` it prints a redefine warning for every item in the global `%INC` (which is now empty because of file2).

I searched the codebase for `%INC` and found that only file1 and file2 use it at all. So what I did was change file2 to this:

```
use vars qw();
require 'file1.pl';

my %INC;     # now lexical, but still the same for all subs in this file
sub bar1 {
  if (!$INC{'foo'}) {
    %INC = &foo();     # this is not breaking stuff any more
  }
  my $hashref = {
    'inc' => \%INC,
  }
  return $hashref;
}

sub bar2 {
  if (!$INC{'foo2'}) {
    %INC = &foo();
  }
}
# and so on
```